# Настройка приложения django

Tags: python, django

помогите пожалуйста с настройкой приложения. Я никак не могу разобраться, что нужно сделать.
Это сама ошибка:

```py
    Internal Server Error: /
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\learning_logs\views.py", line 7, in index
        return render(request, 'index.html')
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
        content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
        return template.render(context, request)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
        return self.template.render(context)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
        return self._render(context)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
        url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
        return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
      File "E:\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
        raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
    django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'topics' not found. 'topics' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

urls.py

```py
    from django.urls import path
     from . import views

    app_name = 'learning_logs'

    urlpatterns = (
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('topics/<int:topic_id>', views.topic, name='topic')
    )
```

views.py

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render

    from .models import Topic


    def index(request):
        return render(request, 'index.html')


    def topic(request, topic_id):
        topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
        entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
        context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
        return render(request, 'topic.html', context)
```

Ну и файл, который выдаёт ошибку
base.html

```html
        <P>
            <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a>
            <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
        </P>
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: В urlpatterns действительно нет ссылки для topics

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{% url 'learning_logs.index' %}">Learning Log</a>
<a href="{% url 'learning_logs.topics' %}">Topics</a>
```

Вроде бы так надо

Comment: Не-а, в данном случае используется именно двоеточие. Подробнее можно почитать на https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/, где указано, что в случае обращения к конкретному приложению используется именно `{% url 'polls:index' %}`, гда `polls` - имя приложения, а `index` - вызываемый паттерн. Ошибка не в этом.

Comment: ммм... ясно тогда я не знаю)